# Service Worker vs Web Worker

Tags: node.js, express, push-notification, socket.io, service-worker

I wanna implement push notification for my website:
Consider we have a shopping site, whenever a user click on one product, the server should push notification to the owner of the product that user (for example John) wants to buy your shoe. (real-time).

I have read some articles about web worker (like socket.io) and service workers, I conclude that service workers are the best choice. Am I true? How can I implement that push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Service Worker is a special kind of Web Workers.
For implementing Web Push Notifications, it's a good choice to use Service Workers (does not work for Safari!). There is a great [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/) explaining how to implement it.